# HTML: letter T in the time format - what for?

Tags: html, time, tags, format

The document http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

says a lot about Date and Time formats:

```
Examples

1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00 corresponds to November 5, 1994, 8:15:30 am, US Eastern Standard Time.

1994-11-05T13:15:30Z corresponds to the same instant.
```

Complete date plus hours, minutes, seconds and a decimal fraction of a
second
      YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)

where:

```
 YYYY = four-digit year
 MM   = two-digit month (01=January, etc.)
 DD   = two-digit day of month (01 through 31)
 hh   = two digits of hour (00 through 23) (am/pm NOT allowed)
 mm   = two digits of minute (00 through 59)
 ss   = two digits of second (00 through 59)
 s    = one or more digits representing a decimal fraction of a second
 TZD  = time zone designator (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)
```

**But, what is T in 1994-11-05T08:15:30 for?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the second paragraph of the **Format** section:

> Note that the "T" appears literally in the string, to indicate the beginning of the time element, as specified in ISO 8601.

Answer (score 3):

It is just a separator, to specify where the time part of the string starts.